# Solaris logadm log rotation

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I would lie to understand how logadm works.
So by looking at the online materials I wrote a small script which redirects a date into a log file and sleeps for 1 second. this will run in a infinite loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while true
do
echo `date` >>/var/tmp/temp.log
sleep 1
done
```

After this I had executed below commands:

```
logadm -w /var/tmp/temp.log -s 100b
logadm -V
```

My intention from above commands is log(/var/tmp/temp.log) should be rotated for every 100 bytes.

But after setting these , when I run the script in background, I see the log file is not rotated.

```
 # ls -lrth /var/tmp/temp.log*
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root        7.2K Jun 15 08:56 /var/tmp/temp.log
 #
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have to call it to do work, e.g. from crontab or manually like `logadm -c /var/tmp/temp.log` (usually placecd in crontab)

Sidenode: you could simply write `date >> /var/tmp/temp.log` w/o echo.

Answer (score 0):

This not how I would normally do this, plus I think you may have misunderstood the -w option.

The -w option updates /etc/logadm.conf with the parameters on the command line, and logadm is then run at 10 minutes past 3am (on the machine I checked).

I took your script and ran it, then ran:
    "logadm -s 100b /var/tmp/temp.log"
and it worked fine. Give it a try! :-)

Comment: I tried this as well. Only when the execute this command logadm -s  it will rotate and create a new file  But it will not continue from there. the new file will be piling up the data in the newly created file. SO it rotates only once. This does not serve the purpose.

Comment: You need to create a crontab entry, in fact there is one by default in Solaris 10 and 11 which runs at 03:10. You also need to add something in /etc/logadm.conf (do a man logadm and logadm.conf). Your entry might look like this: "templog -s 100b /var/tmp/temp.log"